# select-keys with default value

Tags: clojure

Is there a function like `select-keys` but with default values for missing keys?

The reason I'm asking is that I'm using [korma](https://github.com/korma/Korma) to query a database. I found a bug where using `select-keys` is not intuitive when it has no matches.

Example:

```
(delete t
  (where
    (select-keys {:k1 "v1" :k2 "v2"} [:k1])))
```

Same as:

```
(delete t
  (where {:k1 "v1"}))
```

Which translates through korma to something like:

```
delete from t where k1='v1'
```

Nice. `select-keys` creates just the query map I want.

**But**:

```
(delete t
  (where
    (select-keys {:k2 "v2"} [:k1])))
```

Same as:

```
(delete t
  (where {}))
```

Which translates through korma to something like:

```
delete from t
```

Which will delete my entire table `t` :(

I thought about using `(merge defaults (select-keys ...))` or create a function `select-keys-with-default`, but I felt that like `(get m :blah "default")` there should probably be something built-in that I'm missing.

Browsing through the docs, or related functions offered there, didn't show anything useful out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably don't want to execute a query at all when the selection is empty. So something like this would probably do:

```
(when-let [selection (not-empty (select-keys ...))]
  (delete t (where selection)))
```

Comment: I dud not suggest its a bug... Protecting it does make more sense since I don't want default values when I have partial matches.